# mmap load shared object and get function pointer

Tags: c, elf, mmap

I want to dynamically load a library without using functions from `dlfcn.h` i have a folder full of .so files compiled with:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o filename.so filename.c
```

And all of them have an entry function named:

```
void __start(int size, char** cmd);
```

(I know, probably not the best name)

then i try to call `open` over the so, then read the elf header as an `Elf64_Ehdr` load it into memory with `mmap` (i know i should use `mprotect` but i want to make it work first and then add the security) and finally adding the the elf header entry to the pointer returned by mmap (plus an offset of 0x100).

The test code is the following:

```
#include <elf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef void (*ptr_t) (int, char**);

void* alloc_ex_memory(int fd) {
    struct stat s;
    fstat(fd, &s);
    void * ptr = mmap(0, s.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, fd, 0);
    if (ptr == (void *)-1) {
        perror("mmap");
        return NULL;
    }
    return ptr;
}

void* load_ex_file(const char* elfFile) {
    Elf64_Ehdr header;
    void * ptr;
    FILE* file = fopen(elfFile, "rb");
    if(file) {
        fread(&header, 1, sizeof(header), file);

        if (memcmp(header.e_ident, ELFMAG, SELFMAG) == 0) {
            ptr = alloc_ex_memory(fileno(file));
            printf("PTR AT -> %p\n", ptr);
            printf("Entry at -> %lx\n", header.e_entry+256);
            ptr = (header.e_entry + 256);
        } else {
            ptr = NULL;
            }

        fclose(file);
            return ptr;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ptr_t func = load_ex_file(argv[1]);
    printf("POINTER AT: %p\n", func);
    getchar();
    func(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

Let me explain a bit further:
When i run `objdump -d filename.so` i get that the `_start` is at `0x6c0`. The elf header entry point returns `0x5c0` (i compensate it adding 256 in dec).

Also `pmap` shows an executable area being created at lets say `0x7fdf94d0c000`
 so the function pointer direction that i get and which i call is at `0x7fdf94d0c6c0`  this should be the entry point and callable via function pointer. But what i get is, you guessed it: segfault.

Las thing that i would like to point out is that i have the same example running with (`dlopen`, `dlsym`, `dlclose`) but its required that i use the mmap trick. I have seen my professor implement it successfully but i cannot figure out how. (perhaps there is a simpler way that im missing).

I based the code on [this jit example](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/11/05/how-to-jit-an-introduction)

Thank you in advance!

Edit: This is the code of the .c that i compile into .so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void __start(int size, char** cmd) {
    if (size==2) {
        if (!strcmp(cmd[1], "-l")) {
            printf("******.********.*****@udc.es\n");
            return;
        } else if (!strcmp(cmd[1], "-n")) {
            printf("****** ******** *****\n");
            return;
        }
    } else if (size==1) {
            printf("****** ******** ***** (******.********.*****@udc.es)\n");
            return;
    }
    printf("Wrong command syntax: autores [-l | -n]\n");
}
```

Comment: `printf("PTR AT -> %lx\n", ptr);` is the wrong format for a pointer.  `%p` is used to print a pointer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle edited code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> its required that i use the mmap trick. I have seen my professor implement it successfully but i cannot figure out how.

For this to work, your `__start` must be completely stand-alone, and *not* call any other library (you violated that requirement by calling `strcmp` and `printf`).

The moment you call an unresolved symbol, you *ask* the dynamic loader to *resolve* that symbol, and the loader needs all kinds of info for that. That info is normally set up during `dlopen` call. Since you bypassed `dlopen`, it is *not at all* surprising that your program crashes.

Your first step should be to change your code such that `__start` doesn't do anything at all (is empty), and verify that you can then call `__start`. That would confirm that you are computing its address correctly.

Second, add a crash to that code:

```
void __start(...)
{
  int *p = NULL;
  *p = 42;  // should crash here
}
```

and verify that you are observing the crash now. That will confirm that your code is getting called.

Third, remove the crashing code and use *only* direct system calls (e.g. `write(1, "Hello\n", 6)` (but don't call `write` -- you must implement it directly in your library)) to implement whatever you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry about not responding until today: What if i need complex code to be loaded?. Actually the code i uploaded as a sample is the simplest of them all. I cannot implement every syscall by myself. Any ideas?

Comment: @Tretorn "What is I need complex code" -- then you'll need to re-implement part of dynamic loader. But *why* can't you simply `dlopen` this library?